# Flask Input validated before submitted?

Tags: python, forms, flask

I basically want my input to be validated (more than 7 character) before the user hits submit.

I have my input:

```
<form method="POST" action="/send">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="input">
                </div>
                <input type="submit"></form>
```

So to process it in my flask I thought I would do something like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    valid = True
    if len(request.form['input']) < 7:
        valid = False
        flash('Input too short.')
    if request.method == 'POST' and valid:
        variable = request.form['input']
    return render_template('simple.html')
```

This returns me "Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

How can I fix this?

Comment: For dynamic validation you need to use ajax. In case you are validating the form after submitting it, then your form action is pointing to a wrong route, which needs to be changed to `/` from `/send`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the action in the form post from `action="/send"` to `action=""`. Thus, the new line should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

FLASK is not supposed to handle this.  WSGI applications do not handle website input dynamically, so the form would have to be submitted before FLASK could deal with it.

What you want is to use regular expressions in a pattern on the element:

```
<input type="text" pattern=".{8,}" title="Eight or more characters">
```